# Array column field rendering in fields_for … Not Rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

An array filed saved in db as array .. every item in this array should be rendered as text_fields in a fields_for. (In my Rails 4 App with Postgres DB)

which is not rendered as expected ... please looking for you suggestions.

The Code is as follow:

Resource Migration have:

```
t.string :news_outlets, array: true
```

_form.html of parent Post

```
<%= form_for [@post, @post.declare_victory], :html => {} do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: @post.id %>
  <%= f.fields_for :news_outlets do |news_outlet| %>
   <%= render 'news_outlet_fields', f: news_outlet %>
   <div>
   <%= link_to_add_item t('add_news'), news_outlet, '/news_outlet_fields', 'news_outlets'%>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Controller Action in DeclareVictory

```
def create
 @declare_victory = @post.build_declare_victory declare_victory_params
 @declare_victory.user = current_user
 @declare_victory.save

 redirect_to @post, notice: t('success')
end
```

_news_outlet_fields.html partial to be rendered

```
<div class="form-group">
 <%= f.text_field '', id: 'declare_victory_news_outlets', :class => 'form-control',     :placeholder => t('news_outlets.new_news') %>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show the whole form_builder and the controller action? I believe you are missing an instance variable or misstyped the fields_for params.

Comment: code added and updated

Answer (score 1):

The `text_field` needs to include the attribute name for mass assignment to work.

```
<%= f.text_field :news_outlets, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => t('news_outlets.new_news') %>
```

The way you had it, the `name` attribute wouldn't have been right so the params wouldn't have been right so the mass assignment attempt wouldn't have picked up on the new assignment of data from the form.